# Quoting rules in a complex situation

Tags: bash, php, programming

When writing lines of code we sometimes need to consider escaping some characters.

I have come across a situation that I cannot answer on my own

In PHP, the exec command requires a string enclosed in quotes (').
We want to call the command /bin/bash -c which also requires a string enclosed in quotes (')

The solution to this problem is as follows:

```
$line = exec('/bin/bash -c \'read -e -p "Check to confirm string: " -i "'.$preFill.'" input; echo $input\'');
```

There are no problems as long as you do not want to insert a character (') in the text proposed to the user. We can see some example using php -a for interactive mode:

```
php > $preFill = 'I m reach';
php > $line = exec('/bin/bash -c \'read -e -p "Check to confirm string: " -i "'.$preFill.'" input; echo $input\'');
Check to confirm string: I m reach
php >
```

Question is: which escaping rules I have to consider to put in the right way 'I'm reach' into $preFill?

Comment: Spawning a `bash` process seems like a rather roundabout way to read input.

Comment: True, but bash offers a rather effective solution for proposing a pre-filled response to the user. It exists same simple way using php?

Comment: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-read-a-users-input-to-the-php-console would seem far more efficient

Comment: @roaima Please note that my example offers the user a request with a pre-filled response. This is not considered in the way you have suggested.

Comment: PHP's readline library, as suggested by @roaima, does indeed allow for pre-filled response strings.  I have added a reply which attempts to solve your original problem without creating the artifact problem of having to suss out quoting rules when making unnecessary calls to `exec` and `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do some quoting for both the code passed to `bash` and the code passed to `sh` (as started by `php`'s `exec()`):

```
$preFill = 'I m reach';
$prompt = 'Check to confirm string: ';
$bash_code = 'IFS= read -re -p ' .
              escapeshellarg($prompt) .
              ' -i ' .
              escapeshellarg($preFill) .
              ' input; printf "%s\n" "$input"';
$sh_code = 'exec /bin/bash -c ' . escapeshellarg($bash_code);
$output = exec($sh_code);
echo $output;
```

You also forgot [the `IFS=` and `-r` for `read`](/q/209123), and [some quotes around shell parameter expansions](/q/68694), and remember [`echo` can't be used for arbitrary data](/q/65803).

Launching both `sh` and `bash` to prompt the user seems a bit overkill.

Comment: Perfectly works!

Comment: @LucaZappi If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

```
exec('/bin/bash -c \'read -e -p "... " -i "'.$preFill.'" input; echo $input\'');
```

There's a few things wrong here. First, you're running a shell (via `exec`) to run `bash -c ...`, which means that the code that Bash eventually runs must be quoted for the intermediate shell too. You could avoid that by using a function that allows you run `bash` directly, with the arguments in separate array elements (or such), without involving an intermediate shell. Possibly something like [`proc_open()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php).

Second, you're embedding data (that `$preFill` variable) within the code you're passing to Bash. With proper quoting and nice values of the variable, that can work, but it turns painful if `$preFill` can e.g. contain quotes itself. And that pain turns into security vulnerabilities if the variable can be controlled by a user. A better way would be to pass the desired value as a command line argument to the shell, or as an environment variable, and then refer to `$1` or `$val` in the shell program to get the value.

And well, running a shell (or two) for `read` seems exceedingly silly. It might be better to spend some time finding a better way to do that directly from PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Given your Problem Y, how does one properly escape a string when using PHP to invoke a system shell to take advantage of bash's read/readline functionality, you have received some excellent answers on how to do so.

This post attempts to address your Problem X -- your original problem -- which I believe is, how can one capture user input in PHP while also supplying a pre-filled default value?  By employing a native PHP solution, the entire issue of gnarly multi-level character escaping can be avoided, as @roaima hinted at in the comments of your post.

[The PHP documentation for readline](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php) includes [an example by user taneli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readline.php#89805) circa 2009 that shows how to do what you are seeking without having to resort to external shell invocations.  I have expanded that example slightly, but I repeat taneli's work here:

```
$ cat test.php
<?php

function readline_callback($ret)
  {
    global $prompt_answer, $prompt_finished;
    $prompt_answer = $ret;
    $prompt_finished = TRUE;
    readline_callback_handler_remove();
  }

$prompt_string = 'Check to confirm string: ';

readline_callback_handler_install($prompt_string,
                                  'readline_callback');

$preFill = 'foobar';
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($preFill); $i++)
{
  readline_info('pending_input', substr($preFill, $i, 1));
  readline_callback_read_char();
}

$prompt_finished = FALSE;
$prompt_answer   = FALSE;

while (!$prompt_finished)
  readline_callback_read_char();

echo 'You wrote: ' . $prompt_answer . "\n"; 

$prompt_string = 'Check to confirm another string: ';
readline_callback_handler_install($prompt_string,
                                  'readline_callback');

$preFill = $prompt_answer;
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($preFill); $i++)
{
  readline_info('pending_input', substr($preFill, $i, 1));
  readline_callback_read_char();
}

$prompt_finished = FALSE;
$prompt_answer   = FALSE;

while (!$prompt_finished)
  readline_callback_read_char();

echo 'You wrote: ' . $prompt_answer . "\n"; 

?>
```

Output:

```
$ php test.php 
Check to confirm string: foobar
```

I'll append " `is the default`" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
You wrote: foobar is the default
Check to confirm another string: foobar is the default
```

I'll press <kbd>Home</kbd> and put `Now "` at the beginning of the string.  Then I'll press <kbd>End</kbd> and put `" is it's own default.` at the end of the string, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
You wrote: Now "foobar is the default" is it's own default.
```

Comment: Awesome thank you for taking the time over this

Comment: @Jim Love this community. Thanks for appreciated answer, I'll integrate on my procedure for sure.